# How to judge whether a CloudBlob reference is actually referring a existed resource on the Azure Storage?

Tags: c#, azure-storage

I got a CloudBlob via container.GetBlobReference(), this is my code:

```
CloudBlobContainer container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("adcontainer");
CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference(blobUri);
```

I don't know whether this resource is actually on the azure, and I dont want to try due to the slow response.

Or maybe I get the blob in the wrong way in the first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://blog.smarx.com/posts/testing-existence-of-a-windows-azure-blob. You'll need to perform a HEAD request to find out whether the blob exists. `GetBlobReference` doesn't actually do anything (except construct a local object).

BTW, my `WazStorageExtensions` library adds support for `.Exists()`: https://github.com/smarx/WazStorageExtensions